# Using AudioRecord with 8-bit encoding in android

Tags: android, android-audiorecord

I have made an application that records from the phones microphone using the AudioRecord and 16-bit encoding, and I am able to playback the recording. For some compatibility reason I need to use 8-bit encoding, but when I try to run the same program using that encoding I keep getting an Invalid Audio Format. my code is :

```
int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(11025, 
AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, 
AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT);
AudioRecord recordInstance = new AudioRecord(
MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, 11025,
 AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT,
bufferSize);
```

Any one knows what is the problem? According to the documentation AudioRecord is capable of 8-bit encoding.

Comment: I think there is a bug that means currently only 16 bit encoding is possible

Comment: It's pretty easy to convert 16 bit audio samples to 8 bits, if that's all you need ?

Comment: Yes that's all I need but don't know how, can you post the code or a link to a tutorial? Thanks maxsap

Comment: Anyone? I have found this http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5339012&start=45 but doesn't work!

Comment: your error is related with this if in android source code:// PCM_8BIT is not supported at the moment
        if (audioFormat != AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT) {
            loge("getMinBufferSize(): Invalid audio format.");
            return AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE;
        }

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source, it only supports little endian, but Android is writing out big endian.  So you have to convert to little endian and then 8-bit.  This worked for me and you can probably combine the two:

```
for (int i = 0; (offset + i + 1) < bytes.length; i += 2) {
    lens[i] = bytes[offset + i + 1];
    lens[i + 1] = bytes[offset + i];
}
for (int i = 1, j = 0; i < length; i += 2, j++) {
    lens[j] = lens[i];
}
```

Here is a simpler version without endian

```
for (int i = 0, j = 0; (offset + i) < bytes.length; i += 2, j++) {
    lens[j] = bytes[offset + i];
}
```